# Script not working between php pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, httpresponse

The code below runs fine on my first PHP file, but when I load another file and use the same script, it does not appear to work, I get no alert from `alert (idstate);`. The CSS/HTML works fine.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").click(function(){
        if (event.target.id!=""){

            var  idstate=(event.target.id)
            alert (idstate);

            $.post( "somepage.php", { variable: idstate}, function(data) 
            {
                alert(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as `PHP` if it has no `PHP` code within it? Also where is `event` specified?

Comment: like I said i'm a novice, I've only given the script as it works on my first (php) page then it fails on a new page, jquery is loaded from google on both pages

Comment: It might be worth posting the HTML of the two pages in question - or creating a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

when You load another file you have to link that with your php page.`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
<script src="path/custom.js"></script>`

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> is loaded on both pages